# How to handle and catch SocketException?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

For a Java EE app, I'm getting a SocketException in the logs from time to time. One cause of this is when a browser is killed abrupt.

How can I catch those errors? As they do not occur within a specific method that I could surround with try-catch.

```
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:572)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:307)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServletResponseAdapter.flushBuffer(ServletResponseAdapter.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:726)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:655)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:790)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:341)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is internal tomcat logging. You'd need to changer the configuration of tomcat, or even modify the source code. Tomcat has plenty of logging documentation.